# Is this sentence dangled or not?

Tags: grammar, dangling-participles

> **When traveling by sea, knowing your exact location can mean the difference between life and death.**

This is one of the sentences written in Korean high school English textbook. I spent some years in U.S. and had an opportunity to learn English grammar in a few college classes.

What I learned during class was that when we make a participle construction, the subjects of the main clause and the subordinate clause should be the same. If not, it is dangled, therefore we can't use it.

Korean English text books are usually well written, yet it seems to me, in the sentence above, the subjects of each clause are not exactly the same. I want to hear from someone who knows about the grammar rules associated with the participle construction.

Comment: What did you think the subject of the first clause was?

Comment: @BrianHitchcock The subject of the first, *when*, clause is *one* or generic *you*. The subject of the main clause is *knowing your exact location*.

Answer (score 1):

The sentence is OK.  The subject of the sentence is "you", but this is revealed only when one reads "your". This is not dangling or mismatched, the subject is only delayed.

When [you are] traveling, knowing your exact location can mean the difference between life and death.

Comment: 'Technically', this *is* dangling. The subject of the main clause is not "*you*", it's "*knowing your exact location*". I agree that it's perfectly fine, but the subject of the main clause and the subordinate *when*-clause are indeed completely different.

Comment: I know we can use this sentence in every day English. What I want to know is if this sentence showed up in a grammartical test, Would this sentence be marked as correct or not?

Comment: @Araucaria:  "Knowing your exact location when traveling can mean the difference between life and death."  Still dangling?

Comment: @BrianHitchcock No that one isn't, the *-ing* clause there actually *is* the subject of the main clause! :-)

Comment: I disagree. If 'Traveling' is the subject of the main clause, what should be the verb of the main clause? The only verb we can find here is 'can mean' As you pointed out earier, the subject of this sentence is the gerund phrase "knowing your exact location" and "when traveling" is still a participle contruction working as an adverbial of the gerund phrase, 'knowing your exact location'. If we count 'traveling' or 'when traveling' as a subject, then we have two different subjects in one clause, and that's impossible.